# Laravel eager load relationship with added clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

I have two related tables: `Users` & `Images`

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Images');
    }
}

class Image extends Model{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to add a second method on the `User` model named `thumbnails` that would allow me to eager load a specific set of a users `Images` without having to load all of the users images first. Here is the logic:

```
public function thumbnails () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Images')
        ->selectRaw('src, user_id')
        ->where('processed', true)
        ->limit(3);
}
```

Here is how I've been calling this relation:

```
$posts = Post::with(['user','user.thumbnails'])->get();
```

using [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), I was examine the query:

```
"sql": "select src, user_id from \"images\" where \"processed\" = 1 and \"images\".\"user_id\" in (12, 14, 15) limit 3",
```

This only returns the `user.thumbnails` first `Post` model. Is there an issue with my `thumbnails` method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call scope in inner query.

```
class User extends Model{

    public function scopeThumbnails($query)
    {
        return $query->where('processed', true)
        ->limit(3);
    }
}
```

in your controller

```
$posts = Post::with(['user' => function($query) {
    $query->thumbnails();
}])->get();
```

Comment: `$query->thumbnails();` on `user` model but that scope is on `Image` model... how does the `thumbnails` function look in the `user` model?

Comment: @JohnJackson sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your `limit` call isn't limiting 1 user's images to 3, it is limiting the entire query for all the posts' users' images to 3. It will only find 3 total images for all the users.

You can remove that `limit` for now:

```
public function thumbnails()
{
    return $this->images()->where('processed', true);
}
```

Comment: i want to get 3 images for each user & i don't want to select *, i only need the src column. How can i express that correctly?